# multiprocessing.Pool hangs indefinitely after close/join

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I have an indeterminate production issue where a `multiprocessing.Pool` gets stuck and never returns from `join`.

I've managed to reduce the problem down to this small example, and have it somewhat reliably hang.

### Working example:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import time
import multiprocessing.pool

def run_task(i):
    print(f'[{os.getpid()}] task({i}) complete')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    tasks = iter(range(10))
    processes = 4

    pool = multiprocessing.pool.Pool(processes=processes, maxtasksperchild=1)
    running = []
    while True:
        try:
            running = [ f for f in running if not f.ready() ]
            avail = processes - len(running)
            if avail:
                for _ in range(avail):
                    i = next(tasks)
                    print(f'[{os.getpid()}] add task({i})')
                    future = pool.apply_async(run_task, ( i, ))
                    running.append(future)
            else:
                time.sleep(0.1)
        except StopIteration:
            print(f'[{os.getpid()}] all tasks scheduled')
            break

    print(f'[{os.getpid()}] close and join pool')
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    print(f'[{os.getpid()}] all done')
```

Presumably the issue is one of timing, as the failure is indeterminate. As such I have to run it in a loop to get it to hang (although in my experience it will hang on one of the first few iterations).

```
for i in {1..100}; do ./test.py; done
```

The output when it hangs:

```
[15243] add task(0)
[15243] add task(1)
[15243] add task(2)
[15243] add task(3)
[15244] task(0) complete
[15245] task(1) complete
[15246] task(2) complete
[15247] task(3) complete
[15243] add task(4)
[15243] add task(5)
[15251] task(4) complete
[15243] add task(6)
[15243] add task(7)
[15252] task(5) complete
[15253] task(6) complete
[15243] add task(8)
[15243] add task(9)
[15243] all tasks scheduled
[15255] task(8) complete
[15256] task(9) complete
[15243] close and join pool     <-- hangs here indefinitely
```

gdb backtrace of the main process:

```
#0  0x00007fb132b7c6c2 in __GI___waitpid (pid=22857, stat_loc=0x7fff8ef55d5c, options=0) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/waitpid.c:30
#1  0x00000000005d10e5 in os_waitpid_impl (module=<optimised out>, options=0, pid=22857) at ../Modules/posixmodule.c:6941
#2  os_waitpid.lto_priv () at ../Modules/clinic/posixmodule.c.h:2995
#3  0x000000000050a84f in _PyCFunction_FastCallDict (kwargs=<optimised out>, nargs=<optimised out>, args=<optimised out>, func_obj=0x7fb132fea0d8) at ../Objects/methodobject.c:234
#4  _PyCFunction_FastCallKeywords (kwnames=<optimised out>, nargs=<optimised out>, stack=<optimised out>, func=<optimised out>) at ../Objects/methodobject.c:294
#5  call_function.lto_priv () at ../Python/ceval.c:4851
```

gdb backtrace of the child process:

```
#0  0x00007fb1328896d6 in futex_abstimed_wait_cancelable (private=0, abstime=0x0, expected=0, futex_word=0x1c68e40) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/futex-internal.h:205
#1  do_futex_wait (sem=sem@entry=0x1c68e40, abstime=0x0) at sem_waitcommon.c:111
#2  0x00007fb1328897c8 in __new_sem_wait_slow (sem=0x1c68e40, abstime=0x0) at sem_waitcommon.c:181
#3  0x00000000005ab535 in PyThread_acquire_lock_timed (intr_flag=<optimised out>, microseconds=<optimised out>, lock=<optimised out>) at ../Python/thread_pthread.h:386
#4  PyThread_acquire_lock () at ../Python/thread_pthread.h:595
#5  0x0000000000446bf1 in _enter_buffered_busy (self=self@entry=0x7fb13307aa98) at ../Modules/_io/bufferedio.c:292
#6  0x00000000004ce743 in buffered_flush.lto_priv () at ../Python/thread_pthread.h:416
```

---

### Implementation notes:

**Scheduling tasks only when a worker is available:**

Each individual task's priority can change while it's waiting to be executed, so I cannot just enqueue all the tasks at the beginning.

Hence the `running` list and checking `AsyncResult.ready` to determine whether I can execute another task

**maxtasksperchild=1:**

The tasks leak memory, so in order to reclaim the memory lost after each task has run, I cheat and use `maxtasksperchild=1`

---

### Observations:

**sleeping vs busy waiting:**

Interestingly, if I change the `time.sleep(0.1)` to a busy wait, the hang goes away.

```
wait = time.time() + 0.1
while time.time() < wait:
    pass
```

Is it possible that a signal from a child process is missed during the parent's sleep?

**maxtasksperchild=1:**

If I reuse the original child processes, the hang goes away.

---

So it seems to be some interplay between the fact the processes are being destroyed after each task completes, and the parent sleeping.

As a quick fix in production I've changed to sleep to a busy wait, but it feels like an ugly hack, and I'd like to understand what exactly is causing the hang.

- Why does the pool never return from `join`?
- Why does busy waiting instead of sleeping "fix" the problem?
- Why does reusing processes instead of creating new ones each time "fix" the problem?

Comment: Your code works fine on Mac using Python 3.7.4. Output is `[57079] add task(9)
[57079] all tasks scheduled
[57079] close and join pool
[57088] task(8) complete
[57089] task(9) complete
[57079] all done`

Comment: @MauriceMeyer since it's a timing bug (presumably) you may have to run it in a loop to get it to hang (I'll update the question); additionally I'm running 3.6, so perhaps something was fixed?

Comment: Got it, running in the bash loop - the same error appears

Comment: @MauriceMeyer thanks

Comment: In all the multiprocessing documentation the main code is always protected by `if __name__ == '__main__':` - because each process also ‘executes’ the file and you ony want the mainline to actually start creating pools, etc. Have you tried this? Python3 documentation here https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html

Comment: @barny yes I have - I'll update the question to avoid the confusion

Comment: I couldn't get it to fail in the console but on terminal (Ubuntu). Remove `.close()` and `.join()` for fix, you already use the context-manager. When I use `multiprocessing.log_to_stderr(logging.DEBUG)` I can see that there are new processes created _after_ the pool closes when it hangs, but it's not clear to me yet why exactly it evolves how it does.

Comment: @Darkonaut I probably shouldn't be using the context manager tbh - I believe it calls `terminate`, so the tasks will not run to completion?

Comment: @Darkonaut I've removed the context manager

Comment: Using context-manager is fine,  just don't use both together in general. The whole point of using the context-manager is to spare the boiler-plate. In this case here you apparently _need_ to use the context-manager (which terminates _after_ all tasks are processed) because it seems there is a race condition when you use `.join()` with `maxtasksperchild`.

Comment: @Darkonaut I don't believe I need it, as (from the docs) *`__exit__()` calls `terminate()`.*, and for `terminate`: *Stops the worker processes immediately without completing outstanding work.* I **do** want the work to complete first, so I instead have to call `close` - hence, the context manager gives me nothing, and should be removed

Comment: Yeah but `__exit__()` itself is only called after the work is done. Pool terminating is only a problem when you try to register atexit-handlers yourself, but that's another thing. But try it out yourself and see. It failed for me with `.close()` and `.join()` instead of context-manager, that I can say.

Comment: ...If you use asynchronous methods you need to take care of blocking until everything is ready yourself or else the Pool will terminate. Until now I just assumed your code did this but now I see that not all tasks are printing "complete". Using the context-manager would stop the hanging but leaving your first problem untouched. Your issue here yet has nothing to do with the context-manager terminating because you already hang on `.join()`, so `__exit__()` doesn't get called at all.

Comment: @Darkonaut agreed - `pool.close()` will stop accepting new jobs, but allow currently queued jobs to be run; `pool.join()` will then wait until all the queued jobs are finished.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is with the exception, Technically it should not be there and might already be fixed in later versions of python.

```
[15243] add task(4)
[15243] add task(5)
[15251] task(4) complete
[15243] add task(6)
[15243] add task(7)
[15252] task(5) complete
[15253] task(6) complete
[15243] add task(8)
[15243] add task(9)
[15243] all tasks scheduled <-- Exception Called but [15254] or task(7) is not completed
[15255] task(8) complete
[15256] task(9) complete
[15243] close and join pool     <-- hangs here indefinitely
```

Something happens at that point of exception call which might cause task(7) to go into a weird state, apply_async allows callbacks which means that 3.6 might be creating the threads in an unstable manner.

Block wait means your main does not sleep and might be faster in handling this. Check if increasing the wait time or using apply() makes a difference.

I am not sure why reusing "fixes" the problem but might just be that access time is faster and easier to handle.